# How to rename file with a colon in a name on Windows

Tags: windows, ntfs, sftp

Several files were written by SFTP on a Windows server. By mistake the filenames contain an illegal for NTFS characters ":", "\" and I cannot rename, copy them or anything else. Is there some way to solve this problem? Is it possible to solve the issue with SFTP(SSH) access?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Boot with a Linux Bootable USB and try renaming the file in Linux.